# How to set the 'where' clause on a field with comma-seperated values?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a db table with a field with values stored in the `value1,value2,value3,value4` format.
I want to find all the rows where this field contains a defined value, eg. `value3`.

How can I perform a query to search a value in a field like this one?

Comment: If you store your data properly normalized, it is easy.  When you store it like this, it is harder, isn't it!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i have the same problem. `table01` with autoincrement `ids`; `table02` with `columnX` that may contain one or more `ids`. To properly normalize, seems need to create third table ... but... laziness, want to do faster; and those data are not the "main" ("important") data. `select some_column from table01 where ids in (select columnX where columnY = ?)` at first sight looks fast and simple, but does not work...

Comment: @Andris: Does the accepted answer not help?  If not, please ask a new question, cross-referencing this one and explaining why the answers here don't help in your scenario.  Please read the advice in the [SQL tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) page on asking an SQL question.  This question doesn't really meet the modern standards (and barely met the ancient standard when it was written).  IMO, FWIW, doing the job properly is more sensible that botching your way around the system.  However, that's the purist in me coming to the fore.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i tried to use the accepted answer, but seems some error and in my case it does not work. Asked new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75331846/mysql-select-where-in-comma-separated but thinking about whole process at the moment conclusion is that better at first select comma separated values, php convert to array and select where in php array

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET('value3', 'comma separated value here') > 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3e1b/2)

SOURCE

- [MySQL FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Description from MySQL Docs:

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the
>   string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a
>   string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. If the
>   first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type
>   SET, the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic.
>   Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string.
>   Returns NULL if either argument is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `like`:

```
where concat(',', field, ',') like '%,value3,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM tableName
WHERE lower('comma separated values') LIKE 'value3'
```