# mysql select where in (comma separated)

Tags: mysql

`Table01` with columns

```
| Id1 | CommaSeparated |
| 1   | 1,2,3          |
| 2   | 4              |
| 3   | 7,8            |
```

`Table02` with columns

```
| Id2 | SomeValue   |
| 1   | Value01     |
| 7   | Value02     |
| 8   | Value03     |
```

This works: `SELECT SomeValue FROM Table02 WHERE Id2 IN(7,8);`. Get Value02 and Value03.

But `SELECT SomeValue FROM Table02 WHERE Id2 IN( SELECT CommaSeparated FROM Table01 WHERE Id1 = ? );` does not work (get only Value02). Because it takes only the first character/integer from `7,8`.

Tried this

`SELECT SomeValue FROM Table02 WHERE FIND_IN_SET ( Id2, ( SELECT CommaSeparated FROM Table01 WHERE Id1 = 3 ) ) > 0;`

But returns no results...

Any ideas how to solve? Or better to create another table where "connect" the both tables ("normalize data")?

Comment: _"Or better to create another table"_... yes. See [Associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)

Comment: @Phil After some thinking, conclusion is that i can select comma separated values, php convert to array and then select. In both cases seems waste of resources. If i create another table, need to use `lastInsertId`, php modify and then insert into mysql.

Comment: _because it takes only the first character/integer from 7,8_... then make sure the `?` in your PHP code represents a string, not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `with` and `json_table` to transfrom comma separated string to rows :

```
   with t1 as (
   select Id1, CommaSeparated
       from table01
    )
    select t2.SomeValue
    from t1
    join json_table(
      replace(json_array(t1.CommaSeparated), ',', '","'),
      '$[*]' columns (CommaSeparated varchar(50) path '$')
    ) t
    join table02 t2 on t2.Id2 = t.CommaSeparated
    where t1.Id1 = 3
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/C5n5CyfU)

Comment: Tried to include in php, escaped double quotes `'\",\"'`, created `$sql_select = "with cte as ( select Id1, CommaSeparated from table01 ) select cte.Id1, t.CommaSeparated from cte join json_table( replace(json_array(cte.CommaSeparated), ',', '\",\"'),  '$[*]' columns (CommaSeparated varchar(50) path '$') ) t";` and got `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '( replace(json_array(cte.CommaSeparated), ',', '","'), '$[*]' columns (Comma...`

Answer (score 0):

Solution, using "linking" table.

`LinkingTable`

```
| Id | Id1 | Id2 |
| 1  | 3   | 7   |
| 2  | 3   | 8   |
```

`Table01`

```
| Id1 | CommaSeparated |
| 1   | 1,2,3          |
| 2   | 4              |
| 3   | 7,8            |
```

`Table02`

```
| Id2 | SomeValue   |
| 1   | Value01     |
| 7   | Value02     |
| 8   | Value03     |
```

And sql like this `SELECT SomeValue FROM Table02 WHERE Id2 IN( SELECT Id2 FROM LinkingTable WHERE Id1 = 3 );`

Only need to change code, while inserting into `Table02`, need to insert also into `LinkingTable` and use/take `Id1` from `Table01`

Or in my case, i anyway need to select data from `Table01`. So another solution `SELECT CommaSeparated FROM Table01 WHERE Id1 = 3;` For example, result name as `$arr_result`.

Then

```
SELECT SomeValue FROM Table02 WHERE Id2 IN( '. 
rtrim( str_repeat( '?,', count(explode( ',', trim($arr_result[0]['CommaSeparated ']) )) ), ',' ). 
')';
```

If i use `LinkingTable`, i also get "waste of resources". Because in `LinkingTable` need to insert modified `lastInsertId` from `Table02` and `Id` from `Table01`.

The third solution (a bit "crazy").

```
$sql_select = '
SELECT ( SELECT IFNULL ( 
( SELECT `T02`.`SomeValue` 
FROM Table01 `T01` 
INNER JOIN Table02 `T02` 
ON FIND_IN_SET( `T02`.`Id2`, `T01`.`CommaSeparated` ) 
WHERE `T01`.`Id1 ` = 3 AND <another condition>
)
, "empty first value" ) ) 

UNION 

SELECT ( SELECT IFNULL ( 
( SELECT `T02`.`SomeValue` 
FROM Table01 `T01` 
INNER JOIN Table02 `T02` 
ON FIND_IN_SET( `T02`.`Id2`, `T01`.`CommaSeparated` ) 
WHERE `T01`.`Id1 ` = 3 AND <another condition>
)
, "empty second value" ) ) 
;';
```

And `$arr_select = $stmt_select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);`

Get one dimensional array. May use if know maximum number of values (how many values, so many `union`).

At the moment conclusion is that `LinkingTable` solution would be better (less possibility to get something unexpected and, yes, seems in total uses less system resources) ...

Comment: But it saves a lot on a different type of resource: the computing time required to run a query. You can't optimize queries that store comma-separated lists.